# Configuring relationship mapping in EF Core 3.1 so can get currently logged in user's associated data from another entity's table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to extend IdentityUser to add a custom class type entity so I can get the associated record from another table at the same time when `PtUser applicationUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);`is executed to get data of the logged-in user. Currently, it returns me a null value against that property. The **FbUser** property has to be **optional or nullable** in IdentityUser so later if the user links their Facebook account, that data is also loaded with `GetUserAsync()` from the FbUsers table and returned as a property of the logged-in user.

**My extension of IdentityUser to add custom fields(specifically the FbUser)**

```
 public class PtUser : IdentityUser<int>
    {
        [PersonalData]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [PersonalData]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string FbUserId { get; set; }
        public FbUser FbUser { get; set; }
    }
```

**FbUser Class. The object I am trying to retrieve with `GetUserAsync(User)` by using the correct relationship mapping**

```
 public class FbUser
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public string FbUserId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string FbEmail { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public int PtUserId { get; set; }

        public PtUser PtUser { get; set; }
    }
```

**My attempt to create a one-to-one-or-zero relationship between PtUser(parent) and FbUser(child)**

```
 public class PTDbContext : IdentityDbContext<PtUser, PtRole, int>
    {
        public PTDbContext(DbContextOptions<PTDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<PtUser>()
                .HasOne(e => e.FbUser)
                .WithOne(e => e.PtUser)
                .HasForeignKey<PtUser>(e => e.FbUserId);
        }

        public DbSet<FbUser> FbUsers { get; set; }
    }
```

**Currently i am getting null in FbUser property of PtUser. Result while debugging**
[image]

**Thanks a lot!!**

Comment: My guess would be that lazy loading isn't enabled and the `GetUserAsync()` isn't eager loading this new relation for you. Try `context.Entry(applicationUser).Reference(x=>x.FbUser).Load();`  This would require access to the same DbContext dependency instance that the `_userManager` was using.

Comment: @StevePy Wondering if there is a way to enable lazy loading to have that GetUserAsync() eagerly load this related entity.

Comment: If `_userManager` is your own code/implementation, you can add the eager loading by adding `.Include(x =>x.FbUser)` when retrieving the user in question. I.e. inside GetUserAsync there would be something like `var user = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId)` or the like, putting `.Include()` between the DbSet reference (Users) and any `Where` or `Single` etc. methods. Lazy loading on the other hand is configured at the DbContext level. It's more of a "catch all" backdrop to ensure related data can be accessed, but comes with stiff performance costs if relied on.

Comment: @StevePy Thank you again, I am using the default generic implementation of UserManager. I would leave it as is since I do not wanna mess with overriding the methods instead I will load the related entity on the controller-action level from DbContext and that should suffice for my requirement in an easier way.